# heroku run rake db:migrate - rake aborted - TypeError: superclass mismatch for class MultiBox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

After running heroku run rake db:migrate I get:

```
Running `rake db:migrate --trace` attached to terminal... up, run.7762
rake aborted!
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class MultiBox
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/prawn-layout-0.8.4/lib/prawn/layout/grid.rb:191:in `<class:Document>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/prawn-layout-0.8.4/lib/prawn/layout/grid.rb:2:in `<module:Prawn>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/prawn-layout-0.8.4/lib/prawn/layout/grid.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-4.0.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/prawn-layout-0.8.4/lib/prawn/layout.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `rescue in block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block in require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
/app/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

I just resolve a problem with the same error message.

In my case I was executing a migration with a class name previously defined in a model.

Maybe your MultiBox class is defined in some place.

Comment: Is there anything to suggest this problem was actually being encountered though?

Comment: Yup, definitely. One of the causes of super-class mismatch error is this. It will be helpful to many.

Answer (score 0):

I got 'superclass mismatch for class MultiBox' from prawn for every bundle exec I did after I apparently botched a huge git merge.  It was very confusing, because I did not use MultiBox in my app.  When I redid the merge, the error disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Use prawn-table instead of prawn-layout.